# WSManCredSSP setting cannot be enabled

Tags: server, host, hyper-v, credssp

Im trying to set up 2 Hyperv 2016 Server hosts on my local network for remote access, but I just cant get them going.

Servers are configured properly - both running:

- PSRemoting (also tried -skipnetworkprofilechecking)
- Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server, even the firewall is turned off

Computer is configured accordingly:

- Edited the Hosts file, can ping both servers
- Added them to trusted hosts list
- In gpedit added wsman/myhost in both Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials policies.
- Configured COM Security to allow all

**The problem is that I cant execute this cmdlet - Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer "my host"**

It returns **This command cannot be executed because the setting cannot be enabled.**
And when I try to connect either of hosts it returns CredSSP authentification is currently disabled on the local client. But when I run **winrm get winrm/config** it shows that CredSSP is True. I believe, that CredSSP is on, because while ago I was managing another host, and it was working just fine.

Yesterday when I tried to connect via different computer it gave me the same CredSSP error, but I Could run the Enable-WSManCredSSP Command. The difference was that when I tried to connect the host via Hyper-V manager I got Enable Credential Delegation box in loop. When I restarted host and client it again showed the CredSSP error.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a missing configuration on server, that im missing? The Remote Desktop is working fine, but I need to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, are you running PowerShell as an Administrator?

Running `Get-WSManCredSSP` should return either

```
Get-WSManCredSSP : Access is denied.
```

or, if you're running as an Administrator

```
The machine is configured...
This computer is not configured...
```

This should tell you if you've enabled it correctly:

```
[xml]$winrm = winrm get winrm/config/client/auth -format:xml
$winrm.Auth.CredSSP
```

If it's still failing try running you can also try running `Set-WSManQuickConfig -Force` first

Comment: Yes, Im running it as Admin. It returns that the machine is configured. Tried - force. Still no magic. The command you gave returns True. Trust me, Ive tried everything. Made 2 VMs on different host, can connect with the VMs to the second host, everything works. I guess thats something with my computer, because i cant Delegate any host with my pc..

Comment: What happens if you set `-DelegateComputer *`?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix my issue. I just completely stopped the winrm process, deleted all listeners and started it again. The delegatecomputer command executed successfully. Now I can connect to all my hosts with no problem.